# Eloquent save data without casting to avoid bypass 'The payload is invalid.'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to update non-encrypted data in a table with:

```
$results = app(User::class)->all();
$results->each(function(User $item) use($cols) {
    $updates = [];
    foreach($cols as $col) {
        $updates[$col] = encrypt($item->getRawOriginal($col));
    }
    $item->update($updates);
});
```

But it throws error: **The payload is invalid.** Looking at the trace it's trying to decrypt an empty string. Is there a way to disable casting on save?

```
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php(137): Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter->getJsonPayload(NULL)
#1 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(946): Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter->decrypt('', false)
#2 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(578): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->fromEncryptedString('')
#3 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(1633): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->castAttribute('reference', '')
#4 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(1582): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->originalIsEquivalent('reference')
#5 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(1516): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->getDirty()
#6 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(921): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->isDirty()
#7 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(838): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->save(Array)
#8 /src/Commands/MergeDbCommand.php(250): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->update(Array)
```

User model has

```
protected $casts = [
     'reference' => 'encrypted',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue  you have `$casts` in `model` .It trying to `decrypt` null or non encrypted values so it throwing error.

So i think you can do it by disabling `$casts` for `reference`. Then

```
$results = app(User::class)->all();
$results->each(function(User $item) use($cols) {
    $updates = [];
    foreach($cols as $col) {
         try{
          decrypt($item->columnName);
         }catch (DecryptException $e) {
                $updates[$col] = encrypt($item->columnName);
            }
        
    }
    $item->update($updates);
});
```

Comment: The try/catch only catches the issue and prevents any database changes from happening.  I ended up using the DB builder without eloquent for this update.

Comment: as per my understanding try catch only catch decrypted  error not db related

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the DB builder without eloquent for this update

```
$results = DB::table('users')
    ->get();

foreach ($results as $item) {
    $updates = [];
    foreach($cols as $col) {
        if ($item->{$col}) {
            $updates[$col] = encrypt($item->{$col});
        }
    }
    DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', $item->id)
        ->update($updates);
}
```

Comment: if i have not mistaken to understand your code. Will it not encrypt again which already encrypted .then you cant decrypt original value right.Since you mentioned in question few rows already encrypted